# I have 2 lines plotted with plotly-express. How to specify a different pattern for each one, respectively "dash" and "solid"?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I plot 2 lines using the `plotly-express` Python library.
I specify a different color for each one by using the `color_discrete_sequence` argument.
Works well. It's OK for the color part.

Now I'd like to specify a different "pattern" for each line.
Is it possible to do that in a convenient way, as for the colors, just by providing a list of patterns ?

I've tried the `line_dash_sequence` argument that I expected to be the pattern counterpart to  `color_discrete_sequence`.
Unfortunately it doesn't work : the 2 lines use the first pattern.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import time

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [time(x) for x in range(24)],
        "power1": [50 * x for x in range(24)],
        "power2": [52 * x for x in range(24)],
    }
)

fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="timestamp",
    y=["power1", "power2"],
    color_discrete_sequence=["orange", "grey"],
    line_dash_sequence=["dash", "solid"],
)

fig.show()
```

[image]
I guess I'm missing something.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`melt`ing the data and using `color` and `line_dash` with their counterparts `color_discrete_map` and `line_dash_map` seems to work:

```
fig = px.line(
    df.melt(id_vars='timestamp', value_vars=['power1', 'power2']),
    x="timestamp",
    y="value",
    color="variable",
    line_dash="variable",
    color_discrete_map={'power1': 'orange', 'power2': 'gray'},
    line_dash_map={'power1': 'dash', 'power2': 'solid'},
)
```

`color_discrete_sequence` and `line_dash_sequence` also appear to work after converting from wide to long format.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works !
But I still don't understand why its is so unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: My initial guess would be that plotly works better with long-format data rather than wide-format. But I'm not very versed in plotly.

Answer (score 0):

#### in short

use

```py
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y=['y', 'y2'])
for i, line_style in enumerate(['dash', 'dot']):
    fig = fig.update_traces(line=dict(dash=line_style), selector=dict(name=['y', 'y2'][i]))

fig.show()
```

#### details

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# import warnings
# warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
# warnings.filterwarnings('default')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'y': [10, 20, 31, 4, 15, 62, 47, 8, 19, 10],
        'y2': [20, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 39, 50, 20, 11],
        'column1': ['group1', 'group1', 'group2', 'group2', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2'],
    }
)

print("case: base")
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y=['y', 'y2'])
fig = fig.update_layout(**plotly_format_fig_kwargs.model_dump())
fig.show()

print("case: fail -- try line_dash_sequence")
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y=['y', 'y2'], line_dash='column1', line_dash_sequence=['dash', 'dot'])
fig = fig.update_layout(**plotly_format_fig_kwargs.model_dump())
fig.show()

print("case: invesitage line_dash_sequence, find out its not for this usage")
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y', line_dash='column1', line_dash_sequence=['dash', 'dot'])
fig = fig.update_layout(**plotly_format_fig_kwargs.model_dump())
fig.show()

print("case: success -- use update_traces")
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y=['y', 'y2'])
for i, line_style in enumerate(['dash', 'dot']):
    fig = fig.update_traces(line=dict(dash=line_style), selector=dict(name=['y', 'y2'][i]))
fig = fig.update_layout(**plotly_format_fig_kwargs.model_dump())
fig.show()
```

[image]

#### misc

- check api of `line_dash_sequence`

  > **line_dash_sequence** (*list of str*) – Strings should define valid plotly.js dash-patterns. When `line_dash` is set, values in that column are assigned dash-patterns by cycling through `line_dash_sequence` in the order described in `category_orders`, unless the value of `line_dash` is a key in `line_dash_map`.
  >
  > https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line
- *line_dash_sequence is indeed weird... 

  its built for `melt` dataframe, not for multi column case y=['y', 'y2']. 

  idk why, wish there is a better api.*
- just ignore `fig = fig.update_layout(**plotly_format_fig_kwargs.model_dump())`

---

***Update:***

(write as an util func)

```py
def change_lineStyle_forMultiYline(fig: go.Figure, y_arr_lineStyle: list[str | Literal["solid", "dot", "dash", "longdash", "dashdot", "longdashdot"]], opacity=0.5):
    y_arr_colName = [trace.name for trace in fig.data]  # pyright: ignore [reportGeneralTypeIssues]
    if len(y_arr_lineStyle) != len(y_arr_colName):
        raise ValueError("len(y_arr_lineStyle) != len(y_arr_colName)")
    for i, line_style in enumerate(y_arr_lineStyle):
        fig = fig.update_traces(line=dict(dash=line_style), selector=dict(name=y_arr_colName[i]))
    fig = fig.update_traces(opacity=opacity)
    return fig

fig = px.line(df, x='x' y=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
fig = change_lineStyle_forMultiYline(fig, y_arr_lineStyle=["dashdot", "dash", "dot", "dot", "longdashdot"], opacity=0.5)
fig.show()
```